# wx.FileDialog not showing?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've managed to include a FileDialog widget in my wxPython app without error, but I can't get it to show up. Here's my class:

```
class workingFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'UniStaller', size = (300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        basicDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, 'panel', 'Choose a file:', '/Users/student/Desktop/School')
```

My frame shows up, but I don't get a dialog of any kind. Is there a line I need to make it show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
basicDialog.ShowModal()
```

you need to show it